# How to tell when namespace is needed in Avro message?

Tags: avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm having difficulty promoting the use of namespaces in Avro due to several issues. One of the most recent is when should the message include the namespace. I'm at the point now thinking using namespaces are going to be too much of a hassle because of perceived inconsistencies. Recently we have been dealing with the following error from the Confluent Schema Registry:

```
"error_code": 42203,
"message": "Conversion of JSON to Object failed: Failed to convert JSON to Avro: Unknown union branch id"
```

The source of this error appears to be missing namespace identifiers in the message being sent.

For example, within my schema I have a section called `Component` that is defined as follows:

```
{
"name": "component",
"type": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Component",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "typeCode",
                "type": {
                    "type": "enum",
                    "name": "ComponentTypeCode",
                    "symbols": [
                        "PremiumDue",
                        "LoanInterestDue"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "messageFlag",
                "type": "YesNo",
                "doc": "Whether there is a message associated with this entry."
            },
            {
                "name": "amountDue",
                "type": "string",
                "doc": "Amount of the specified component. For example 123.78"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

This can be sent without a namespace without issue:

```
{
    "component": [
        {
            "typeCode": "AppliedDividend",
            "messageFlag": "Yes",
            "amountDue": "192775.34"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, in another part of the schema, I have an enum defined like this:

```
{
"name": "otherLetterCode",
"type": [
    "null",
    {
        "type": "enum",
        "name": "OtherLetterCode",
        "symbols": [
            "PaidUpDateModLetter",
            "IndemnityLetter"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

In the message, it must be sent like this:

```
"otherLetterCode": {
     "my.namespace.OtherLetterCode": "IndemnityLetter"
}
```

This seems inconsistent. If the entire schema is defined within a namespace, shouldn't we either have to a) use the namespace throughout the messages or b) not have to use a namespace within the message at all? I would expect the `component` to look like this:

```
{
    "my.namespace.component": [
        {
            "typeCode": "AppliedDividend",
            "messageFlag": "Yes",
            "amountDue": "192775.34"
        }
    ]
}
```

Does it make sense to continue to use namespaces, and if so, how can we be sure that our variety of system clients will be able to create messages that have namespace values spelled out in the appropriate places, assuming they will not be able to use automatic code generation utilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `otherLetterCode` is a union of two possible values. The avro specification for JSON is the way most people would expect (i.e. field name is key name and field value is key value) except in the case of unions. You can look at the spec here: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding, but in the case of unions, if the value is non-null it expects the namespaced type to be included.

Specifically:

```
For example, the union schema ["null","string","Foo"], where Foo is a record name, would encode:

- null as null;
- the string "a" as {"string": "a"}; and
- a Foo instance as {"Foo": {...}}, where {...} indicates the JSON encoding of a Foo instance.
```

Comment: More specifically, "Foo" refers to the record's fully qualified name

Comment: What would happen in a situation where no namespace was defined?

Comment: If there is supposed to be a namespace but one isn't there you will end up with the "Unknown union branch" error you are seeing.

Comment: After looking through it and remembering a similar concern about how the JSON representation of a null/string union should appear, this is now making more sense. I believe even without a defined namespace, the _type_ still needs to be declared. Meaning removing the namespace might make it a little easier for the client, but more difficult for the rest of us.